# sphinx with matlabdomain seems to get into an infinite loop when reading source

Tags: matlab, python-sphinx

I am trying to generate matlab documentation with sphinx but I get into what seems like an infinite loop when reading the source and I have no idea why.

So I get it to work as expected with a simple matlab function but it hangs when I include another function. This is my index.rst and it works when the only file in the folder is a matlab function func1 but it doesn't work when I add another matlab function func2. It is nothing special with func2, just some plotting with scatter3 with colormaps.

```
Welcome to documentation!
=========================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. currentmodule:: new_folder

.. autofunction:: func1


:func:`func1`

Indices and tables
==================
* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was due to the existence of many % in a row inside one of the matlab functions (func2 in my tests).

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the matlab-domain extension. Can you write the `func2` here, that makes it behave like that?